# How to add Customer Group Selector in Registration form in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, registration

I'm a Newbie in Magento 2. I am working in magento 2.3. My client wants me to add customer group selector field in registration form. I would like to develop a plugin for that. Please give me some ideas to do it.

Comment: Make your question clearer, add code snippet or image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new on Magento i guess you also don't have the skills to create an extension to add customers group on the registration page.

Magento 2 Community edition does not have this functionality that is only available on Enterprise edition.

My suggestion for you is to use an existing customer attributes extension available on the market.

Good luck!